# Add Folders to Root of Zip Using Ionic Zip Library

Tags: c#, zip, dotnetzip

what I'm trying to do is add a list of folders and files all to the root of my Zip file, using the Ionic Zip library (c#).

Here's what I have so far

```
string k = "B:/My Documents/Workspace";
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
   {   
       //add directory, give it a name
       zip.AddDirectory(k);
       zip.Save("t.zip");
   }
}
```

Now, I want my zip to be looking like this.

- t.zip

  - Random Files and Folder

But it's looking like this.

- t.zip

  - t (folder)

    - Random files and folders

Any help would be appreciated, Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

The default behavior of AddDirectory should add the contents of the directory to the root path in the zipfile, without creating a subdirectory.

There is a second overload of AddDirectory, which adds a parameter to specify what the path of the added files should be within the zipfile.  But since you want the files to go into the root directory, this would just be an empty string.

```
zip.AddDirectory(k, "");
```

See [this documentation](http://dotnetzip.herobo.com/DNZHelp/html/ff003409-f713-7b75-e11e-08a92403a6c2.htm) for more info.

None of this explains where your subfolder is coming from.  I suspect the problem is from something else in the code.  It might be useful to run this in debug and see what 'k' equals when you call AddDirectory, or to print out all the "entries" in the zip.Entries collection.

Comment: Thanks I'm going to try that out

Comment: Okay, I tried that and it still created the subfolder, any other ideas?

Comment: In my testing, AddDirectory isn't creating a subfolder--even if I don't pass the empty string, it still doesn't create a subfolder.  Is there anything else in your code that might be creating that folder?

Comment: Not that I know of, that's literally the only code I have, word for word lol, and I tried it with all different types of data.  I could swear though that at one point, it worked as intended and only recently did is start doing that.  Let me check my libraries and the version of Ionic that I'm using

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
    {
        zip.AddFiles(sourcefiles, ""); //For saving things at root of your zip
        foreach (DirectoryInfo objFile in objDir.GetDirectories())
        {
            zip.AddDirectory(objFile.FullName, objFile.Name); ///For saving subdirectories within zip
        }
        zip.Save(pathzipfile + ".zip");
    }
```

Comment: this is great! thanks buddy. you did awesome job by using this line of code zip.AddFiles(sourcefiles, ""); //For saving things at root of your zip

Answer (score 0):

Why not try something like this:

```
foreach (var file in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(k))
{
    zip.AddFile(file);
}
```

To get the directories and files to an unlimited depth, combine that with a recursion method based on `System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories("path")` - should be pretty straightforward methinks.

Comment: Oh yeah and testing just now, I did this: `var imagePath = basePath + "Content\\Images\\"; zip.AddDirectory(imagePath);` - it added the files and folders from my Images folder recursively straight to the root like you would want yours to do.