# DotNetZip-lib - Do not only add the files in a directory, but include the whole directory

Tags: c#

I'm currently having the problem that the DotNetZip-library does not work as expected.
I have a treeview that contains different nodes:

[image]

Each of these nodes is filled with folders and files:

[image]

As the name already suggests, the *Add folder* button can be used to add a directory. 
For example, the "Audio" folder was added to the treeview, using a recursive algorithm which adds all subfolders and files of the "Audio" folder.

The next step is to create a zip file which contains all elements of treeview. 
To create the zip file, I am using the following code:

```
private void InitializeArchiveContents(int nodeIndex, string currentDirectory)
    {
        foreach (TreeNode node in explorerTreeView1.Nodes[nodeIndex].Nodes)
        {
            FileAttributes attr = File.GetAttributes(node.Tag.ToString());
            if ((attr & FileAttributes.Directory) == FileAttributes.Directory)
            {
                zip.AddDirectory(node.Tag.ToString(), currentDirectory);
                currentDirectory += String.Format("{0}/", Path.GetDirectoryName(node.Text));
            }
            else
            {
                zip.AddFile(node.Tag.ToString(), currentDirectory);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Problem:** Unfortunately, the zip file created by the code above does not contain the the "Audio" folder.

Here is a short explanation of the code above:

It takes the current node index (for example 0 stands for the *program*-node above) and then checks if it is a file or a directory. I added the whole path to the files to the `Tag`-property of the TreeNodes. The `currentDirectory` stands for the current folder in the archive. So at the beginning of my class I added a folder by name (`AddDirectoryByName`) to the zip. It's then called *Program* and in this folder inside the zip all the content from the TreeView's *program* node should be filled in.
So every time a new directory comes to it I update the `currentDirectory` to keep the path inside the ZIP up-to-date to make sure the files are in the correct folders in the end.

So, if the path is a directory it adds a directory into the archive and if it is a file, it adds the file.

To make it clearer:

TreeView:

- Program directory

  - Audio

    - File1.wav
    - File2.mp3

and then in the *Program*-directory if the ZIP it should be like that:

- Program

  - Audio

    - File1.wav
    - File2.mp3

So the same structure. The problem now is that it does something like that in the end:

- Program

  - File1.wav
  - File2.mp3

So, the *Audio*-folder is not added by the `zip.AddDirectory`-method, only its content.
But I want that it also creates that folder to make it look like in the treeview.

Could you tell me how I could do that? I just want the DotNetZip-lib to create that subfolder.

I found this: [Add Folders to Root of Zip Using Ionic Zip Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13129141/add-folders-to-root-of-zip-using-ionic-zip-library)

The problem is, that the OP there has a problem which is my aim. Create a sub folder!
Thanks ;)

If something is not clear, ask!

Comment: I think something wrong with `currentDirectory`. When you call for the first time `zip.AddDirectory(node.Tag.ToString(), currentDirectory);` files are added to the root folder, because `currentDirectory` is empty (or root folder). Can you check value of `current Directory` by the debugger? And this line makes no sense for me `currentDirectory += String.Format("{0}/", Path.GetDirectoryName(node.Text));`

Comment: Yes, it is the root folder at the beginning. I will check that with breakpoints tomorrow. The last line is there to keep the current directory in the archive up-to-date to paste the files into the right directory.

Comment: If you have another folder in the program directory (Video for example), `currentDirectory` at the end will by `Audio/Video/`.

Comment: Well, right. So, I will check that tomorrow and then it would be great if you help me to find a good solution.

Comment: @shfire So when calling the function "InitializeArchiveContents" the currentDirectory-parameter is the root directory of course.
It has the value "Program/" at the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change recursion logic. And you dont need to use `AddDirectory` to add directory with entire content, because some files can be deleted from Treeview. Instead of this, you can add files to archive directly from Treeview.

```
InitializeArchiveContents(explorerTreeView1[nodeIndex], "Program/")
```

......

```
private void InitializeArchiveContents(TreeNode node, string currentDirectory)
{
    foreach (var node in node.Nodes)
    {
        var attr = File.GetAttributes(node.Tag.ToString());
        if ((attr & FileAttributes.Directory) == FileAttributes.Directory)
        {
            var tmpDir = string.Format("{0}/{1}", currentDirectory, node.Text);
            zip.AddDirectoryByName(tmpDir);
            InitializeArchiveContents(node, tmpDir);
        }
        else
        {
            zip.AddFile(node.Tag.ToString(), currentDirectory);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks! I allowed myself to try the code and it throws me an exception in the marked line:
http://www.trade-programming.de/pixelkram/yczdeivgwn.png

It sais: An element with the same key was already added.
Any ideas how I could fix this?

Comment: What is the value of `tmpDir`? Are you creating a new archive or updating an existing?

Comment: So, at the beginning the value is "Program/". I am creating a new archive.

Comment: `tmpDir` mast be `string.Format("{0}/{1}", currentDirectory, node.Text)`

Comment: Well ok, I debugged with breakpoints and saw that the problem was that there was a "Path.GetDirectoryName", which you edited, I think.
With your help I did it! Thanks so much!